# Powershell 'where' statement -notcontains

Tags: regex, powershell, where-clause

I have a simple excerpt form a larger script, basically I'm trying to do a recursive file search, including sub-directories (and any child of the exclude).

```
clear
$Exclude = "T:\temp\Archive\cst"
$list = Get-ChildItem -Path T:\temp\Archive -Recurse -Directory
$list | where {$_.fullname -notlike $Exclude} | ForEach-Object {
Write-Host "--------------------------------------"
$_.fullname
Write-Host "--------------------------------------"
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $_.fullname -File
$files.count
}
```

At the moment this script will exclude the **T:\temp\Archive\cst** directory, but not the **T:\temp\Archive\cst\artwork** directory.  I'm struggling to overcome this simple thing.

I've tried the **-notlike** (which I didn't really expect to work) but also the **-notcontains** which I was hopeful of.

Can anyone offer any advice,  I'm thinking it would require a regex match which I'm reading up on now, but not very familiar with.

In the future the **$exclude** variable will be an array of strings (directories) but at the moment just trying to get it to work with a straight string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
where {$_.fullname -notlike "$Exclude*"}
```

You could also try

```
where {$_.fullname -notmatch [regex]::Escape($Exclude) }
```

but the notlike apporach is easier.

Comment: So simple.  I ended up using the first example provided.  Didn't know wildcards were accepted like that!

Comment: That's the point of the `-like` operator (wildcards that is). :-) Check out `get-help about_comparison_operators` for more information.

Answer (score 3):

When used without wildcards the `-like` operator does the same as the `-eq` operator. If you want to exclude a folder `T:\temp\Archive\cst` and everything below it, you need something like this:

```
$Exclude = 'T:\temp\Archive\cst'

Get-ChildItem -Path T:\temp\Archive -Recurse -Directory | ? {
  $_.FullName -ne $Exclude -and
  $_.FullName -notlike "$Exclude\*"
} | ...
```

`-notlike "$Exclude\*"` would only exclude subfolders of `$Exclude`, not the folder itself, and `-notlike "$Exclude*"` would also exclude folders like `T:\temp\Archive\cstring`, which may be undesired.

The `-contains` operator is used to check if a list of values contains a particular value. It doesn't check if a string contains a particular substring.

See [`Get-Help about_Comparison_Operators`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847759.aspx) for further information.

Comment: Great point, that had just occurred to me that what I said could exclude wanted files. I had just updated my answer to reflect that note.

Comment: So I take away from this that if the **$Exclude** contains **"T:\Temp\Archive\CST"** then using **$Exclude*** should be fine, however if **$Exclude** contains the trailing slash ("T:\Temp\Archive\CST\") than it would not exclude the original excluded folder.  **Just tested and that's exactly what happens**

Comment: @mhouston100 Beware that without a trailing backslash (or forward slash for that matter) using `$Exclude*` would also exclude *other* subfolders of `T:\Temp\Archive` starting with `cst`, e.g. `T:\Temp\Archive\csthingie`.

Comment: I've marked yours as answered for that reason, more complete.  In the folder where this script will run it is entirely possible to have **cstthingy** as a folder.

Comment: I have noticed that if the **$Exclude** string has a trailing slash then this does not work and nothing is excluded.  Not a big deal in this case and not hard to sanitize but just worth noting.

Comment: Normally you'd just not put a trailing backslash in the string. However, if necessary you could sanitize it with a replacement like this: `$Exclude = $Exclude -replace '[\\/]+$'`.

Answer (score 2):

Thought I would add to this as I recently had a similar problem answered.  You can use the -notcontains condition, but the thing that is counter intuitive is that the $exclude array needs to be at the start of the expression.

Here is an example.

If I perform the following no items are excluded and it returns "a","b","c","d"

```
   $result = @()
   $ItemArray = @("a","b","c","d")
   $exclusionArray = @("b","c")
   $ItemArray | Where-Object { $_ -notcontains $exclusionArray }
```

If I switch the variables around in the expression then it works and returns "a","d".

```
   $result = @()
   $ItemArray = @("a","b","c","d")
   $exclusionArray = @("b","c")
   $ItemArray | Where-Object { $exclusionArray -notcontains $_ }
```

I am not sure why the arrays have to be this way around to work.  If anyone else can explain that would be great.

EDITED 12/12/20 - I now know that the other operation to use is "-in" as in

```
$_ -notin  $exclusionArray
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
$Exclude = "T:\temp\Archive\cst"
```

To:

```
$Exclude = "T:\temp\Archive\cst\*"
```

This will still return the folder CST as it is a child item of Archive, but will exclude anything under cst.

Or:

```
 $Exclude = "T:\temp\Archive\cst*
```

But that will also exclude anyfiles that start with "cst" under Archive.  Same goes for Graimer's answer, jsut be aware of the trailing \ and if it's important to what you are doing

Comment: I ended up going with **Graimer's** answer as the **$Exclude** list will be provided by the user at runtime so safer than expecting them to exclude the *

Answer (score 1):

For those looking for a similar answer, what I ended up going with (to parse an array paths for a wildcard match):

```
# Declare variables
[string]$rootdir = "T:\temp\Archive"
[String[]]$Exclude = "T:\temp\Archive\cst", "T:\temp\archive\as"
[int]$days = 90

# Create Directory list minus excluded directories and their children
$list = Get-ChildItem -Path $rootdir -Recurse -Directory | where {$path = $_.fullname; -not @($exclude | ? {$path -like $_ -or $path -like "$_\*" }) }
```

Provides what I needed.